# Retrieve Power BI data set published to the service using a desktop pibx file

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have created a data model and published to the power BI service and now trying to access that Power BI data set through the new BI desktop Pibx file but keep getting the below error. It worked fine on my personal laptop (Which was on Windows 10) my office PC is on Windows 7.

[Image of the thrown error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzAPS.png)

Comment: Have you tried signing in and out of PowerBI Desktop?

Comment: it was due to proxy set up and manged to get it fixed after by passing the Proxy server :)